# How to override a method in objC which includes a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, overriding

I know how to override a method in Objective-C. I do it as follow and it's working all fine. The problem is I don't know how to do it when the original method includes a block. I would appreciate if you can fix/add to my code below.

In code below, I have commented out the method with the block which I don't know how to override. FYI: I am overriding the code related to push notification service.

```
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Class objectClass = object_getClass(delegate);
    NSString *newClassName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Custom_%@", NSStringFromClass(objectClass)];
    Class modDelegate = NSClassFromString(newClassName);

    if (modDelegate == nil)
    {
        modDelegate = objc_allocateClassPair(objectClass, [newClassName UTF8String], 0);

        SEL selectorToOverride4 = @selector(application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:);
        SEL selectorToOverride5 = @selector(application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:);
        SEL selectorToOverride6 = @selector(application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:);
        //SEL selectorToOverride7 = @selector(application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:);

        // get the info on the method we're going to override
        Method m4 = class_getInstanceMethod(objectClass, selectorToOverride4);
        Method m5 = class_getInstanceMethod(objectClass, selectorToOverride5);
        Method m6 = class_getInstanceMethod(objectClass, selectorToOverride6);
        //Method m7 = class_getInstanceMethod(objectClass, selectorToOverride7);

        // add the method to the new class
        class_addMethod(modDelegate, selectorToOverride4, (IMP)didRegisterSuccess, method_getTypeEncoding(m4));
        class_addMethod(modDelegate, selectorToOverride5, (IMP)didRegisterFailure, method_getTypeEncoding(m5));
        class_addMethod(modDelegate, selectorToOverride6, (IMP)didReceiveRemoteNotification, method_getTypeEncoding(m6));
        //class_addMethod(modDelegate, selectorToOverride7, (IMP)didReceiveRemoteNotificationFetchCompletionHandler, method_getTypeEncoding(m7));

        // register the new class with the runtime
        objc_registerClassPair(modDelegate);
    }

    // change the class of the object
    object_setClass(delegate, modDelegate);

void didRegisterSuccess(id self, SEL _cmd, UIApplication *application, NSData *deviceToken)
{
    [base didRegisterSuccess:application deviceToken:deviceToken];
}

void didRegisterFailure(id self, SEL _cmd, UIApplication *application, NSError *error)
{
    [base didRegisterFailure:application error:error];
}

void didReceiveRemoteNotification(id self, SEL _cmd, UIApplication *application, NSDictionary *userInfo)
{
    [base didReceiveRemoteNotification:application userInfo:userInfo];
}

/*
void didReceiveRemoteNotificationFetchCompletionHandler(id self, SEL _cmd, UIApplication *application, NSDictionary *userInfo, void(^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult)handler)
{

}
 */
```

Comment: Why are you overriding the methods like this anyway? Why aren't you doing it the normal way?

Comment: @rmaddy well, I need it because I am working on an Air Native Extension! if you know how to do it, please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocks are just Objective-C objects, so you can simply use `id` as Type of the block:

```
void didReceiveRemoteNotificationFetchCompletionHandler(id self, SEL _cmd, UIApplication *application, NSDictionary *userInfo, id handler)
{

}
```

Or you can define your own Type for your block, and use it:

```
typedef void (^YourBlockType)(UIBackgroundFetchResult);

void didReceiveRemoteNotificationFetchCompletionHandler(id self, SEL _cmd, UIApplication *application, NSDictionary *userInfo, YourBlockType handler)
{

}
```